# Running JUnit tests with Embedded Jboss

Tags: jboss, junit, embedded-jboss

I need to run junit tests for classes using ejb3 beans. In our case setting up jboss just for this purpose is not an option and therefore we need an alternative way to simulate the ejb communication. I've read that this should be possible with Embedded Jboss's EJB3StandaloneBootstrapper, but the problem is that I cannot get it to work properly.

I was wondering if anyone of you know of a good tutorial which explains all the details, including how to configure the various files (embedded-jboss-beans.xml, ejb3-interceptor-aop.xml etc). With the embedded jboss package came a tutorial for junit with example code, however, the build script in it failed. If you don't know a tutorial, do you at least know where I could find a working example of embedded jboss + junit?

Answer (score 1):

I did a [presentation on using the embedded JBoss](http://www.innovationontherun.com/presentation-files/ete2007-dimarco-java-ee-unit-testing.pdf) and had a download with [example code](http://www.innovationontherun.com/presentation-files/ete2007-dimarco-staying-cutting-edge.pdf).  Hope this helps.

Comment: its http://www.innovationontherun.com/presentation-files/ete2007-dimarco-java-ee-unit-testing-code.zip

Comment: Do you have an updated tutorial?  I've been trying to get this one to run with the beta3 .jars and having a tough time.  I would love to be able to use embedded jboss for my testing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Jakarta Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus) is the proper framework to run such tests.